# Geometry of inner products between the unit vector and several given vectors

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, euclidean-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of all unit complex-valued $d$-dimensional vectors, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal{S} \triangleq \left\{ \mathbf{s}\in \mathbb{C}^{d} \mid \mathbf{s}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{s}=1 \right\}.
$$
Arbitrarily given $N$ complex-valued vectors $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\cdots$, $\mathbf{a}_{N}\in \mathbb{C}^d$, where the integer $N\ge d$. Are there some good geometric properties of the following set
$$
\mathcal{A} = \left\{ \left(\left|  \mathbf{s}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{a}_1 \right|^2,\cdots, \left|  \mathbf{s}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{a}_N \right|^2 \right)^{\mathrm{T}} \mid \mathbf{s}\in \mathcal{S} \right\}.
$$

---

The numerical results show that $\mathcal{A}$ has a nice shape (like an ellipsold).
[image: Sampled points (after an appropriate translate) of \mathcal{A} with N=2 and d=3]
[image: Sampled points (after an appropriate translate) of \mathcal{A} with N=3 and d=3]

Comment: In the first formula, should $N$ be replaced by $d$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko You are right. It has been modified.

Comment: Non-obviously, the MathJax LaTeX processor is greedier than the HTML parser, so that LaTeX in alt text creates trouble.  The actual LaTeX commands themselves seem OK, only the `$` being problematic.  I have edited to remove them.